# How can I make POJO class when have so many different keys in Retrofit

Tags: json, kotlin, retrofit, pojo

I have URL having lots of datas with some value of exchage rates.

```
{
  "update":1583931550455,

  "JPYINR":[0.70513,0.0073300004,1.0504443,0.6978,0.70545,0.6999,0.71],
  "CNYGBP":[0.11117,-0.0004400015,-0.3942312,0.11161,0.11142,0.11084,0.11175],
  "GBPUSD":[1.2944314,0.0062696934,0.48671137,1.2881618,1.2885933,1.2848021,1.2976564],

  ...
}
```

I want to make POJO class to get Retrofit response, but problem is... datas have different keys!

Over 100 keys in that URL.

So, I can't write all key values in POJO class. It is not efficient I think.

Below is my POJO class..

**data class Rate**

```
data class Rate(
    var update: Long,
    var rate: Array<Double>
)
```

As you see,

property rate couldn't recognize correct value. Actually it takes null value.

(Of course, update property takes 1583931550455 from URL data)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while but still I already came to a conclusion of what you need.

```
data class Rate(
var update: Long,
val result: LinkedTreeMap<Double, Any>)
```

turns out that on the ResponseTreeMapclass you just needed to pass the second class type parameter as Any and it can be down casted to anything that you need.

also i leave here a nice tool that can help you map your json responses into kotlin plain objects/DTOs:

https://app.quicktype.io/